# Left to right scrolling list tag content one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need smooth text scrolling bar something like ticker, where text will scroll smoothly left to right one after another and also need hover effect to stop the animation. I tried with jQuery but not quite getting it.

```
      <ul id="ticker">
          <li>this is first title</li>
          <li>this is second title</li>
          <li>this is third title</li>
          <li>this is fourth title</li>
          <li>this is fifth title</li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap your ul and li elements in a marquee and then do the following:

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="3" direction="left" 
    onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
       <ul id="ticker">
          this is first title    
          this is second title
          this is third title
          this is fourth title
          this is fifth title
      </ul> 
</marquee>
```

CSS

```
marquee {
    text-indent:-100px;
    width:450px;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldaf9/46/) is a working example in jsfiddle

Comment: its not working, its scrolling all the list tag element togather

Comment: @monir009 ok so what changes do u want me to make?

Comment: @monir009 you want the to scroll in one line?

Comment: well I mentioned it one after another, just like a news ticker, its scrolling in one line now but its scrolling together I need it like when one first line is completely gone then second will come, another problem is mouse hover function not working

Comment: and need the scrolling smoothly , javascript or jQuery?

Comment: it does stop when i mouse hover

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="list">

  <li id="1" style="margin-bottom:80px;">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.</li>
  <li id="2" style="margin-bottom:80px;">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: while answering please add some description to understand your solution.